# Difference between `go get` and `git clone`?

Tags: git, go, github, version-control, gitlab

I had a problem with `go-modbus` in an [issue](https://github.com/goburrow/modbus/issues/30) in Github.
Author suggested me to use:

```
$ go get github.com/goburrow/modbus
```

**instead of**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/goburrow/modbus.git
```

What is the difference between that two commands?

Comment: `go get` also retrieves transitive dependencies of the project while `git clone` doesn't. Also `go get` clone into the right folder while with `git clone` you have to do it correct yourself.

Comment: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies. It is a good explanation of `go get`.

Comment: what's reason of downvotes?

Comment: @peterSO I google difference between two command but not any appear, so I thought maybe this difference and usage of each one useful for other and me.

Comment: One command is for git, the other is for go. The git command has no knowledge, or care for, go.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `git clone` command will clone a repo into a newly created directory, while `go get` downloads and installs the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies.

Comment: Plus, neither the named packages nor the dependencies need to be Git repositories. Other VCS are supported as well.